# Chromium-embedded for Delphi - TChromiumOSR.OnPaint is not fired when a modal window is shown

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, delphi-xe4

I'm using the Off-screen rendering component `TChromiumOSR` in the dcef3 package - the Delphi wrapper for `Chromium-embedded` library.

## Situation

`FormA` contains a `TChromiumOSR` and paints the output.
Modal `FormB` modifies the web page by executing some `js` code against  `FormA.TChromiumOSR`.

## Issue

The `TChromiumOSR.OnPaint` event (in `FormA`) is not triggered until `FormB.ShowModal` returns.

## Notes

- There is **no such issue** in the above described situation (under a modal form) with the standard `TChromium` control.

I assume the `TForm.ShowModal' method only blocks the input of the background forms, but not the painting?

Or does it caused by the internal working of cef3?

Anyway, how to solve it? Thanks.

[dcef3 master branch is here](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. I've tried with the latest DCEF3 (Delphi 2009) modify an _offline_ HTML document by using `Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript` and the paint event has been triggered even that was called from a modal form. Could you be more specific in what you're doing? Anyway, to invalidate the view you can call `Browser.Host.Invalidate(PET_VIEW);` after you modify your document. However, I think this should work without this explicit call. Better try to craft an MVCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the source of the problem - it's **not a bug in cef3 or dcef3** but was caused by my improper use of [Delphi Event Bus](https://github.com/spinettaro/delphi-event-bus), and the following are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. In one the 'delphi event bus' handler, the program shows a **modal** form at this point the execution of the main thread is blocked.
2. On top of the modal form, the user doing certain actions will start a background thread, which in turn will send a message to the main thread, which in turn will calls the 'delphi event bus' to post another new event, which in turn will execute some `js` code to update the web page inside `dcef3`, which in turn will trigger some of the `dcef3` events (in the main thread), and here is where the program stuck - since the `TEventBus.Post()` method is locked by a `TCriticalSection`.

**Solution**:
In Step #1, don't call `ShowModal` directly, but use a technique such as `PostMessage` winapi to 'delay' the execution of `ShowModal`.

I'm not sure if I have described it clearly...

Answer (score 1):

I've succeeded updating an HTML element by using the [**ExecuteJavaScript**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefFrame.html#ExecuteJavaScript(constCefString&,constCefString&,int)) method called from a modal form. But you might have use CEF V8 as well (that's what I haven't tested). For cases when you need to invalidate the current view manually, you can call [**Invalidate**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefBrowserHost.html#Invalidate(PaintElementType)):

```
MyChromiumOSR.Browser.Host.Invalidate(PET_VIEW);
```

But that's workaround rather than solution. Invalidating of relevant elements should happen by the CEF engine for you. And if you come up with an MCVE, I can investigate more about your specific problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, so I went ahead and made a MCVE, it turned out that the issue is not inside dcef3, but resides somewhere inside my code! I'll check further and post the details once I've fixed it.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in my code which prevents windows messages which are supposed to trigger the `TChromiumOSR.OnPaint` event from floating... It must be **related to ShowModal()**, but I'm stuck and have no idea at the moment, will keep trying...

Comment: Well, I can't see your code so I cannot help. Have you tried to invalidate the view manually by that `Invalidate` call? Could you share your MCVE? I'll try to test mine in Tokyo in the meantime but I'm a bit skeptical as the CEF renderer doesn't rely on Windows (VCL) message pump..

Comment: No, even in Tokyo works everything as should. Hence I need to see your code.

Comment: Sorry, but the MCVE I created earlier **cannot** reproduce the the issue described in the original post. I'm digging into the `ShowModal` method now...

Comment: Well, my best guess is that this issue is not related to CEF. In any case, so long I cannot see MCVE, I'm out of help.

Comment: A note FWIW at this moment - I've tried `MyChromiumOSR.Browser.Host.Invalidate(lCefRect, PET_VIEW);` and it deosn't help.